# Run a command in a new tab in terminal

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, terminal, applescript

I'm trying to write a script that could run several commands in several tabs in the terminal.
I found a lot of informations about it, but it doesn't work as I want it to. So I probably need AppleScript.

• This code run a command in a new window:

```vb
tell app "Terminal"
   do script "echo hello"
end tell
```

• And this one open a new tab

```vb
tell application "Terminal"
  activate
  tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "t" using {command down}
  end tell
end tell
```

But I didn't figured out how to "mix" them. Any idea ?

Comment: first of all why you want to run commands in seperate tabs? do you want to run new process for each command?

Comment: Yes, such as node, mongod etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "t" using {command down}
    end tell
    do script "echo hello" in selected tab of the front window
end tell
```

Comment: @WizzyBoom I had the same problem back in 2014 (node server + front webapp + mongodb), I don't really remember what I ended up with, something kind of dirty with the server starting gulp itself. Now I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all which totally does the job. Concerning mongodb, it wouldn't make sense to start it along with the server, it should already be up. I personally manage mongodb/elasticsearch/redis with docker + kitematic on macOS. Launchrocket is also quite good at it